# Python Twitter Tools - handling twitter 404 and 401 API errors

Tags: python, api, twitter, error-handling, exception

I'm getting 404 and 401 errors while querying the Twitter API, and my script to pull friends breaks on account of not handling the exceptions.
Have researched and tried adding the following try/except provision, but the exceptions are not logged, and the for loop stops.

```
first = 0
last = 15
while last < len(list)+16: #while last group of 15 items is lower than number of items in list#
    for item in list[first:last]: #parses twitter IDs in the list by groups of 15#
        try:
            results = twitter.friends.ids(skip_status="true",include_user_entities="false",count ="5000",user_id=item) #API query#
            results = str(results)
            text_file = open("output.txt", "a") #creates empty or opens current txt output / change path to desired output#
            text_file.write(str(item) + "," + results + "\n") #adds twitter ID, resulting friends list, and a line skip to the txt output#
            text_file.close()
            break
        except ValueError:
            text_file = open("output.txt", "a") #creates empty or opens current txt output / change path to desired output#
            text_file.write(str(item) + "," + "ERROR" + "\n") #adds twitter ID, resulting friends list, and a line skip to the txt output#
            text_file.close()
    print "Succesfully processed users " + str(list[first:last]) #returns recently processed group of 15 users#
    first = first + 15 #updates list navigation to move on to next group of 15#
    last = last + 15
    time.sleep(1000) #suspends activities for 1000 seconds to respect rate limit#
```

Have also looked into building if statements based on http response headers, but I don't understand how to plugin the Python Twitter Tools "response.headers.get('h')" to do so. What would be the best way to handle and record these exceptions and make the script continue pulling the data?

Comment: You don't want to `break` where you do!

Comment: Thanks, have removed the break and the "ValueError", now it works correctly until it reaches an error. Then that error is correctly recorded, but the for loop stops, instead of continuing to the next one.. I'm reading up on exceptions.. should I add an else statement to continue with the loop?

Comment: Try adding a `continue` after the last line of the exception handler.

Comment: Works perfectly, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `break` at the end of the `try:` block and add a `continue` at the end of the `except:` block. i.e.:

```
first = 0
last = 15
while last < len(list)+16: #while last group of 15 items is lower than number of items in list#
    for item in list[first:last]: #parses twitter IDs in the list by groups of 15#
        try:
            results = twitter.friends.ids(skip_status="true",include_user_entities="false",count ="5000",user_id=item) #API query#
            results = str(results)
            text_file = open("output.txt", "a") #creates empty or opens current txt output / change path to desired output#
            text_file.write(str(item) + "," + results + "\n") #adds twitter ID, resulting friends list, and a line skip to the txt output#
            text_file.close()
            # break is not needed here!
        except ValueError:
            text_file = open("output.txt", "a") #creates empty or opens current txt output / change path to desired output#
            text_file.write(str(item) + "," + "ERROR" + "\n") #adds twitter ID, resulting friends list, and a line skip to the txt output#
            text_file.close()
            continue # You have dealt with the exception so don't stop
    print "Succesfully processed users " + str(list[first:last]) #returns recently processed group of 15 users#
    first = first + 15 #updates list navigation to move on to next group of 15#
    last = last + 15
    time.sleep(1000) #suspends activities for 1000 seconds to respect rate limit#
```

*Transferred from comments to preserve.*